# SQL Like function for similar strings

Tags: sql

SQL DBO Database:

```
ID   PROPERTY   POSTCODE   ROAD          BOROUGH      TOWN            DISTRICT
1     49        CF15 778   LONDON ROAD   HERTFORD     HERTFORDSHIRE   NORTH
2     8         CB17 798   BULMERS CLOSE WARE         HERTFORDSHIRE   SOUTH
3     49        CG12 684   LONDON ROAD   HITCHIN      HERTFORDSHIRE   NORTH
4     12        CB12 236   JULIAN STREET HERTFORD     HERTFORDSHIRE   WEST
5     32        CB15 678   LONDON ROAD   ST ALBANS    HERTFORDSHIRE   SOUTH
```

***Example:***

*User Searches:* 49 London Road, Kent

*SQL displays:*
Can not find '49 London Road, Kent'
Similar results for '49 London Road, Kent'

- 49 London Road, Hertford
- 49 London Road, Hitchin
- 32 London Road, St Albans

---

I am trying to think the best way to code this.

At the moment I have two forms, one for user input and the second to display the results.

I just want the user to input text in a textbox and the SQL to search for any words within that text box that matches with the table.

Comment: Delete your comment and add the note to your question by clicking the edit link below the tags.

Comment: You say "I know it's not the SQL" but `LIKE '%'+@address+'%` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Is the bulleted list the desired result?

Comment: Maybe you need to check the wild card characters for Sql Server. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: I've just worked it out that it wasn't the SQL at fault but I need to now find a work around whereby if a sting contains any word in that table then it will show the data. I am now going to have multiple user inputs  until I can find another work around with just using one user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need to do.

> If User Searches : 49 London Road, Kent

Split this string into an array of strings in this manner (*here we are splitting using as ' ' space character*)

1. 49
2. London
3. Road,
4. Kent

For this list of strings (*in your code*)

1. 49 - *Determine if the first position is numeric-digits*
2. London - *determine if this is a letters only without digits*
3. Road, - *determine if this is also letters and you may need to ignore the comma or non alphabet characters*
4. Kent - *determine if this is letters only also*.

When you have finished determining or splitting user input like this in your code, you now go to the `sql` and check string 1 in the property field eg '49'
in this case you will get Property Ids 1 and 3
You then check for the remaining strings.

Here is the sample query that I would produce

```
Select * From MyTable where Property like '%49%' or Road like '%London Road%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Just think of Google Search, it pulls the main result but also any
> similar matches.

The LIKE operator in SQL produces uses logic that is very different from Google search syntax and query processing logic. Nevertheless, the LIKE operator is powerful for string matching. There are plentY of resources to check, please see resources at bottom of this text.

For your specific case, using a statement like this:

```
select Property, Road, Postcode, Borough, Town, District from addresses WHERE Road LIKE "London Road,%"
```

will produce all the items you have listed in your question.

However the results depend on the quality of the data and the format its in. Maybe adding more structure to the Road column would allow you to write more specific query and get better result. Also note that in real life cases, LIKE maybe harmful as it may sometimes require all rows to be examined without index.

References:
[Ref1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-like/)
[Ref2](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-like-logical-operator-introduction-and-overview/)

**Edit**

> I just want the user to input text in a textbox and the SQL to search
> for any words within that text box that matches with the table.

Based on your changed question, One way you can do something close to the desired result is to break the input into tokens and use OR with LIKE in your SELECT as in :

```
SELECT ID, Property, PostCode, Road, Borough, Town, District from T WHERE
Road LIKE "%token1%" OR Road LIKE "%token2%" OR ROAD LIKE "%token3%";
```

The number of ORs will depend on the number of tokens your input text box has. Say you have the user enter the followong tokens in the search text box:

LONDON ROAD STREET

Your SQL will be:

```
SELECT ID, Property, PostCode, Road, Borough, Town, District from T WHERE
Road LIKE "%LONDON%" OR Road LIKE "%ROAD%" OR ROAD LIKE "%STREET%"
```

Here is an example:
[SQL Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uYTw52DkP87cjL1Ww5dNqa/0)

Note that this approach may produce duplicates. There are many ways you can create a list without duplicates, for example you could use DISTINCT ID on the SQL, or a Dictionary Class on your program. Again, performance may be an issue for such queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think I am explaining myself correctly. I know it's not the SQL i'm now having issues with. I've gotta think of a workaround now which I can't seem to manage.

Comment: It could help you if you show the data you have stored and the result you expect as well as what the user enters.

Comment: I've re-worked my question a bit, hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: I've made an upadte to my previous answer based on your new question under 'EDIT'. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a work around which should be good to use for now until I rework my database, unfortunately theres so many tables and rows I gotta change about haha. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Try full text search
Needs to be something like below. Not tested. I don't have access to full text components

```sql
create table X (ID int,  PROPERTY int,
    POSTCODE nvarchar(300), ROAD nvarchar(300),
    BOROUGH nvarchar(300), TOWN  nvarchar(300),
    DISTRICT  nvarchar(300));

go

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG xxx;  

go

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON x 
 (   
  property  
     Language 1033,  
  postcode  
     Language 1033,  
  road   
     Language 1033,  
  BOROUGH   
     Language 1033,  
  town   
     Language 1033,
  DISTRICT
    Language 1033
 )   
  KEY INDEX PK_xxxxx   
      ON xxx;   


go 


insert into X values (1, 49, 'CF15 778',   'LONDON ROAD',   'HERTFORD',     'HERTFORDSHIRE',   'NORTH');
insert into X values (2,8,   'CB17 798',   'BULMERS CLOSE', 'WARE',         'HERTFORDSHIRE',   'SOUTH');
insert into X values (3 , 49,'CG12 684',   'LONDON ROAD',   'HITCHIN',      'HERTFORDSHIRE',   'NORTH');
insert into X values (4  ,12,'CB12 236',   'JULIAN STREET', 'HERTFORD',     'HERTFORDSHIRE',   'WEST');
insert into X values (5,32,  'CB15 678',   'LONDON ROAD',   'ST ALBANS',    'HERTFORDSHIRE',   'SOUTH');

go

SELECT
    . . . . 
FROM 
     . . .
WHERE
    CONTAINS(. . . .,"49 London Road, Kent")
```

Comment: I must be going mad but this keeps popping up and i'm stairing at it and I can't see what the issue is. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.'`

Comment: @Nixfee what I did initially wouldn't work. Have to do more for it

Comment: I've never used it before, i'll try and check on some examples. Thank you!